# Adding newer ubuntu versions to XEN in /usr/lib/xen-tools/ with Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, ubuntu-12.04, xen

I am trying to setup a VPS (`Ubuntu 12.04`) on my dedicated server (`Debian Squeeze`) using XEN virtualization.

Currently I am able to setup `Ubuntu 10.04` without any issues, but I would like to use `Ubuntu 12.04`. When attempting to use `xen-tools` to try and use a the `precise` dist (`Ubuntu 12.04`) it tells me the distro isn't available, look in `/usr/lib/xen-tools/`. A quick `ls` shows:

```
centos-4.d  debian.d          fedora-core-11.d  fedora-core-5.d  fedora-core-9.d  hardy.d     lenny.d     sarge.d    testing.d
centos-5.d  edgy.d            fedora-core-12.d  fedora-core-6.d  feisty.d         intrepid.d  lucid.d     sid.d      wheezy.d
common.sh   etch.d            fedora-core-13.d  fedora-core-7.d  gentoo.d         jaunty.d    maverick.d  squeeze.d
dapper.d    fedora-core-10.d  fedora-core-4.d   fedora-core-8.d  gutsy.d          karmic.d    natty.d     stable.d
```

I have been looking around but simply cannot figure out how to add `precise` to this list so I can use that instead of `lucid`. Would anyone care to point out how to accomplish this?

Please point out if there is any necessary information missing in order to answer the question.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To add new distributions you have to create a new directory in `/usr/lib/xen-tools`, as described by [xen-tools FAQs](http://xen-tools.org/software/xen-tools/faq.html).

Squeeze's `xen-tools` package doesn't have scripts for `precise` but you can borrow them from [wheezy's package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/xen-tools/download).

Use

```
dpkg -x xen-tools_4.3.1-1_all.deb
```

to extract the files and then move `precise.d` to`/usr/lib/xen-tools`.

Answer (score 0):

precise.d is a symlink to karmic.d

```
cd /usr/lib/xen-tools
ln -s karmic.d precise.d
```